# Why is handling POST requests with Django REST Framework getting slow for body sizes greater than 1024 characters?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF.  I found that receiving a POST with more than 1024 characters causes a ~1 second penalty, while anything less than that is effectively free.  I've simplified this into this trivial example:

views.py:

```
import time
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from django.http import HttpResponse

@api_view(['POST'])
def test_endpoint(request):
    t = time.time()
    data = request.body
    total_time = time.time() - t

    print('got post data:', round(total_time, 3))
    return HttpResponse('body size:{} time:{}'.format(len(data), round(total_time, 3)))
```

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test_endpoint', test_endpoint),
]
```

You can see that *all* I'm doing is reading the `request.body` and measuring the time it takes to do so.  Then I respond with that time, and the len of the `request.body` (to prove I accessed it).

Then I execute these curls:

```
$ time curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_endpoint -d 0123456782345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567901234567890123456789012345678901234567
body size:1024 time:0.0
real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.009s
$ time curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_endpoint -d 01234567823456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345679012345678901234567890123456789012345678
body size:1025 time:0.999
real    0m1.020s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.006s
```

You can see the second one has *one* extra character, and that causes a ~1 second penalty to ready `request.body`.

Why is that? How can I prevent this?

I made this as vanilla as I could. I created an new project with `django-admin startproject helloworld_project .`.  I put the code above into it.  And running it locally with `python manage.py runserver`.  I don't have a webserver in front of it; I'm accessing it directly with my browser. That's all I'm doing.

Also, I'm doing this on `Django==1.11`.  This problem seems to go away on `Django==2.0`.  I cannot easily upgrade to `2.0`. Is there a workaround for this issue on `1.11`?

Comment: what server do you use? `nginx+uwsgi`, `werkzeug` or ...? I cannot reproduce same problem with default `runserver`

Comment: Same results with werkzeug. Probably additional information needed on how your app being deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go deeper and see where the real slowness is.

This [function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.16/django/http/request.py#L328) is called from [body](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.16/django/http/request.py#L261) property.

```
def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._read_started = True
    try:
        import time
        t = time.time()
        data = self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)  # HERE(!)
        total_time = time.time() - t
        print('TOTAL TIME: ', total_time)
        return data
    except IOError as e:
        six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

For 1024 characters:
`TOTAL TIME:  3.123283386230469e-05`

For 1025 characters: `TOTAL TIME:  0.991084098815918`

---

Hmm... This problem is gone in Django 2.0, let's see [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#requests-and-responses):

> **Requests and Responses**
>
> *The runserver Web server supports HTTP 1.1.*

HTTP 1.1 Supports [chunked transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) while HTTP 1.0 does not. I think this can explain the slow behavior.

---

> Is there a workaround for this issue on 1.11?

With default `runserver` I believe that the answer is **No**. But you won't use it in production, right? Any other production server like `gunicorn`, `uWSGI` supports HTTP 1.1.